# Installing a Python Library on Windows 10; with proxy set on

Tags: python, windows, ssl, pip

I'm trying to install the Fabric library on a Windows 10 with proxy (workstation). I still get the same output about SSL with this command:

```
pip install fabric
```

or

```
pip install C:\Users\myuser\dir\fabric-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.
```

Examples are here:

CMD -> pip install fabric:

> pip install fabric
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/fabric/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/fabric/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/fabric/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/fabric/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/fabric/
> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/fabric/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/fabric/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))) - skipping
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fabric
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for fabric

CMD -> pip install C:\Users\myuser\dir\fabric-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl:

> Processing c:\users\myuser\dir\fabric-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/invoke/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/invoke/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/invoke/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/invoke/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/invoke/
> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/invoke/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/invoke/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))) - skipping
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement invoke<2.0,>=1.3 (from fabric)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for invoke<2.0,>=1.3

My question is how can I bypass the validation of SSL or install the library manually since my scenario have proxy validation.

Comment: Unfortunately not enough is known about your proxy settings. So I will only assume that you made a typical error of setting the https_proxy as `https://...` instead of `http://...` and marked the question as duplicate. If this is not the reason then please add the relevant information to your question.

Comment: *"how can I bypass the validation of SSL"* - this is not an error of SSL (certificate)  __validation__ so it cannot be bypassed. This kind of error often happens if one tries to connect with TLS to a server (or proxy) which does not support TLS.